# JQuery on click event not always firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax call that fires on a click but it seems to be intermittently working and I can't seem to pinpoint the issue...

It seems to be working perfectly one minute and the next not even registering a click?

```
<input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Assign" id="assignJounrey<?php echo $callID; ?>" name="assignJounrey<?php echo $callID; ?>">
<input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="Unassign" id="unassignJounrey<?php echo $callID; ?>" name="unassignJounrey<?php echo $callID; ?>" style="display: none;">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#assignJounrey<?php echo $callID; ?>').unbind().click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'assign-journey-calls.php?JourneyID=<?php echo $journeyID; ?>&Call=<?php echo $callID; ?>',
            success: function(){
                $("#assignJounrey<?php echo $callID; ?>").fadeOut();
                $("#unassignJounrey<?php echo $callID; ?>").show();
            }
        });
    });
    $('#unassignJounrey<?php echo $callID; ?>').unbind().click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'unassign-journey-calls.php?JourneyID=<?php echo $journeyID; ?>&Call=<?php echo $callID; ?>',
            success: function(){
                $("#unassignJounrey<?php echo $callID; ?>").fadeOut();
                $("#assignJounrey<?php echo $callID; ?>").show();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Is there anything that i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why the unbind?

Comment: remove unbind() and check

Comment: use unbind().bind("click, function(){}).

Comment: Is this all of your code?  Are you adding/removing/replacing any html?   Could be that you need event delegation if you're rebuilding those after document read (eg via ajax)

Comment: Also, `unbind`?  Really?  It's been discouraged since 2011!  > As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .off() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.